# Simple counter in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Simple question:

How to make a counter for every call of the function bellow? I want to click on a button to call the popup with the new number for every click.

I tried but it is not working. I am newbie and appreciate any light to help me.
This is a general question, can be from any programming language, so any idea will be welcome. I just want to understand the logic.

```
var i = 0;

function next(){
  Browser.msgBox(i);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: VBA and Google Script are 2 different things, but from your code, I think you are talking about Google Apps Script. It might be better if you edit your question to add `google-apps-script` and remove the Excel & VBA tag.

Comment: This is a general question. All programming is quite similar but I will edit anyway, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Counter in Google Apps Script**

This is run as a spreadsheet bound script.

```
function nextI() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if(!ps.getProperty('curI')) {//if it doesn't exist
    ps.setProperty('curI', 0);//create it and set it to zero
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(ps.getProperty('curI'));//Display it
  }else{
    ps.setProperty('curI', Number(ps.getProperty('curI'))+1);//if it exists then increment it 
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(ps.getProperty('curI'));//display it
  }
}
```

[PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

[UI Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)

[Spreadsheet App Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Answer (score 0):

a simple way:

```js
function counter(){
  PSd = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();

    var n = PSd.getProperty('count');
          n++
           PSd.setProperty('count', n);
  Browser.msgBox(n,Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

no need to create a condition, he creates and increases the value without any "test"